# How to find the min steps to cross the river?

Tags: algorithm

The Fibonacci sequence is defined using the following recursive formula:

```
F(0) = 0
F(1) = 1
F(M) = F(M - 1) + F(M - 2) if M >= 2
```

A small frog wants to get to the other side of a river. The frog is initially located at one bank of the river (position −1) and wants to get to the other bank (position N). The frog can jump over any distance F(K), where F(K) is the K-th Fibonacci number. Luckily, there are many leaves on the river, and the frog can jump between the leaves, but only in the direction of the bank at position N.

The leaves on the river are represented in a zero-indexed array A consisting of N integers. Consecutive elements of array A represent consecutive positions from 0 to N − 1 on the river. Array A contains only 0s and/or 1s:

0 represents a position without a leaf;
1 represents a position containing a leaf.
The goal is to count the minimum number of jumps in which the frog can get to the other side of the river (from position −1 to position N). The frog can jump between positions −1 and N (the banks of the river) and every position containing a leaf.

For example, consider array A such that:

```
A[0] = 0
A[1] = 0
A[2] = 0
A[3] = 1
A[4] = 1
A[5] = 0
A[6] = 1
A[7] = 0
A[8] = 0
A[9] = 0
A[10] = 0
```

The frog can make three jumps of length F(5) = 5, F(3) = 2 and F(5) = 5.

Write a function:

function solution(A);

that, given a zero-indexed array A consisting of N integers, returns the minimum number of jumps by which the frog can get to the other side of the river. If the frog cannot reach the other side of the river, the function should return −1.

For example, given:

```
A[0] = 0
A[1] = 0
A[2] = 0
A[3] = 1
A[4] = 1
A[5] = 0
A[6] = 1
A[7] = 0
A[8] = 0
A[9] = 0
A[10] = 0
```

the function should return 3, as explained above.

Assume that:

N is an integer within the range [0..100,000];
each element of array A is an integer that can have one of the following values: 0, 1.
Complexity:

expected worst-case time complexity is O(N*log(N));
expected worst-case space complexity is O(N), beyond input storage (not counting the storage required for input arguments).
Elements of input arrays can be modified.

// below is my uncompleted code in Javascript. I can't solve it...

```
function solution(A) {
    var fibs = [];

    var length = A.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        fibs.push(fib(i));
    }
    // [ 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55 ]
    var currentLeafIndex = -1;
    while(currentLeafIndex < length + 1) {
        var possibleLeaves = [];
        i = 0;
        while(currentLeafIndex + fibs[i]< length) {
            var thisIndex = currentLeafIndex + fibs[i];
            if(A[thisIndex] === 1 ) {
                possibleLeaves.push(thisIndex);
            }
            i++;
        }

        console.log(possibleLeaves);
        return; // debug
    }

}

function fib(number) {
    /*
      F(0) = 0
    F(1) = 1
    F(M) = F(M - 1) + F(M - 2) if M >= 2
     */
    if(number === 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    if(number === 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    return fib(number -1) +fib(number -2);

}

var inputA = [0,0,0, 1,1,0, 1,0,0, 0,0];
var result = solution(inputA);

console.log("result is: " + result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a guise on a typical dynamic programming problem: the rod cutting problem. Setup a recurrence like:

Minimum jumps(n) = minimum(n-k) for all k in fibonacci sequence

In other words, take one jump, and then recursively find the number of jumps you need to the end now that you've jumped once. If there are no jumps possible, return an arbitrarily high number like 100,000.

Note: the recursive formula is very expensive, so store the values instead of recomputing them repeatedly

Comment: Why do you call it dynamic programming? which part makes it dynamic?

Comment: So generally you have a recursive algorithm that recomputes values repeatedly (like for example if you jump 1, then 1, or jump 2, you're in the same position) and so the recursive version is expensive. So you store the values after you compute them so you can avoid *re-computing* them. I'm summarizing a bit, but I wasn't the one who called it dynamic :D

Comment: Thanks for introducing the idea of dynamic programming. This concept is new to me.